# How can I list available operating system signals by name in a cross-platform way in Go?

Tags: unix, go, signals, cross-platform

Let's say I'm implementing the `kill` program in Go. I can accept numeric signals and PIDs from the commandline and send them to `syscall.Kill` no problem.

However, I don't know how to implement the "string" form of signal dispatch, e.g. `kill -INT 12345`.

The real use case is a part of a larger program that prompts the user to send kill signals; not a replacement for `kill`.

**Question:**

How can I convert valid signal names to signal numbers on any supported platform, at runtime (or at least without writing per-platform code to be run at compile time)?

**What I've tried:**

- Keep a static map of signal names to numbers. This doesn't work in a cross-platform way (for example, different signal lists are returned by `kill -l` on Mac OSX versus a modern Linux versus an older Linux, for example). The only way to make this solution work in general would be to make maps for every OS, which would require me to know the behavior of every OS, and keep up to date as they add new signal support.
- Shell out to the GNU `kill` tool and capture the signal lists from it. This is inelegant and kind of a paradox, and also requires a) being able to find `kill`, b) having the ability/permission to exec subprocesses, and c) being able to predict/parse the output of `kill`-the-binary.
- Use the various `Signal` types' `String` method. This just returns strings containing the signal number, e.g. `os.Signal(4).String() == "signal 4"`, which is not useful.
- Call the private function [`runtime.signame`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/?m=all#signame), which does exactly what I want. `go://linkname` hacks will work, but I'm assuming that this sort of thing is frowned-upon for a reason.

**Ideas/Things I Haven't Tried:**

- Use CGo somehow. I'd rather not venture into CGO territory for a project that is otherwise not low-level/needful of native integration at all. If that's the only option, I will, but have no idea where to start.
- Use templating and code generation to build lists of signals based on external sources at compile time. This is not preferable for the same reasons as CGo.
- Reflect and parse the members of `syscall` that start with `SIG` somehow. I am told that this is not possible because names are compiled away; is it possible that, for something as fundamental as signal names, there's someplace they're *not* compiled away?

Comment: Isn't it possible to call `strsignal` and/or use `sys_siglist` array?

Comment: Potentially; I gave it a shot, but haven't used Cgo before, so it kept failing to store output values in the go struct I was using. I'll keep poking at it and post here if I get anywhere; do you know of any example code for that?

Comment: In C: `for (int i=0; i<NSIG; i++) printf("%d %s (short %s)\n",i,sys_siglist[i],sys_signame[i]);`. I did not practice Go, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commit [d455e41](https://github.com/golang/sys/commit/d455e41777fca6e8a5a79e34a14b8368bc11d9ba) added this feature in March 2019 as `sys/unix.SignalNum()` and is thus available at least since Go 1.13. More details in GitHub issue [#28027](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28027).

From the [documentation](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#SignalNum) of the `golang.org/x/sys/unix` package:

> `func SignalNum(s string) syscall.Signal`
>
> SignalNum returns the syscall.Signal for signal named s, or 0 if a signal with such name is not found. The signal name should start with "SIG".

To answer a similar question, "how can I list the names of all available signals (on a given Unix-like platform)", we can use the inverse function `sys/unix.SignalName()`:

```golang
    import "golang.org/x/sys/unix"

    // See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28027#issuecomment-427377759
    // for why looping in range 0,255 is enough.
    for i := syscall.Signal(0); i < syscall.Signal(255); i++ {
        name := unix.SignalName(i)
        // Signal numbers are not guaranteed to be contiguous.
        if name != "" {
            fmt.Println(name)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

*Update* some time after I posted the below answer, Golang's stdlib acquired this functionality. An answer describing how to use that functionality was posted by @marco.m and accepted; the below is not recommended unless the version of Go you are using pre-dates the availability of the right tool for the job.

Since no answers were posted, I'll post the less-than-ideal solution I was able to use by "breaking into" a private signal-enumeration function inside Go's standard library.

The [`signame`](https://golang.org/src/runtime/signal_unix.go?h=signame#L20) internal function can get a signal name by number on Unix and Windows. To call it, you have to use the [`linkname`/assembler workaround](https://sitano.github.io/2016/04/28/golang-private/). Basically, make a file in your project called `empty.s` or similar, with no contents, and then a function declaration like so:

```
//go:linkname signame runtime.signame
func signame(sig uint32) string
```

Then, you can get a list of all signals known by the operating system by calling `signame` on an increasing number until it doesn't return a value, like so:

```
signum := uint32(0)
signalmap = make(map[uint32]string)
for len(signame(signum)) > 0 {
    words := strings.Fields(signame(signum))
    if words[0] == "signal"  || ! strings.HasPrefix(words[0], "SIG") {
        signalmap[signum] = ""
    } else {
        // Remove leading SIG and trailing colon.
        signalmap[signum] = strings.TrimRight(words[0][3:], ":")
    }
    signum++
}
```

After that runs, `signalmap` will have keys for every signal that can be sent on the current operating system. It will have an empty string where Go doesn't think the OS has a name for the signal (the [kill(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) may name some signals that Go won't return names for, I've found, but it's usually the higher-numbered/nonstandard ones), or a string name, e.g. "INT" where a name can be found.

**This behavior is undocumented, subject to change, and may not hold true on some platforms.** It would be nice if this were made public, though.